# How do I close a Safari alert that's taller then the screen?

Tags: safari, alert

[image]

Oh, come on! I can't close this stupid alert because it's taller than the screen itself. Pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> just re-opens the alert again. How do I close a Safari alert that's taller then the screen?

(I have unsaved work in several other tabs.)

Comment: Try disabling javascript & block pop-up windows - prefs > security. Installing AdBlock might be a good idea once you've killed it & saved your work. I'm assuming you know that's a phishing attempt & not to ring the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but there are very few things you can do:

- Force restart safari and hope it doesn't re-open this page.
- Try disabling Wi-Fi and keep pressing enter.

Also, I believe the latest Safari updates contain a fix for this type of malware.